# Unable to keep the newest version of an Open source code in my server

Tags: svn, git

I have tried to test a few Open source codes.
The problem is that these projects changes rapidly such that my code is daily old.

For example, I started yesterday to test the code [at](http://cnprog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/).
The code at my server is already old.
The problem is that all changes which I have done are not included in the newest code when I upload their branch to my server.

Perhaps, it possible to somehow rebase their newest code to my branch by **Git.** Their code is controlled by **SVN**.

**How can you include the newest changes of the original project to my branch?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use git-svn: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn

Comment: It seems that git-svn is not in Mac by default. I cannot find it even by MacPorts. I will take a look if I find it from an Ubuntu box.

Comment: Git-svn can be easily installed in Ubuntu by apt-get.

Comment: $git svn update; updates the app. Does it overwrite my changes with the ones in the original repo?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to learn more about [Vendor Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).